# Delete certificate for all users

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler

We need to delete some organization related certificates from client machine. That machine contain 3 users, we need to login as admin and some how get access to all user certificates and delete those certificates.

Currently to delete certificates we need to enter into specific user account and manually delete certificate from **Internet Options -> Content tab -> Certificates**, which is time consuming.

Hence, I tried using X509Store:

```
private void RemoveCertificates(string storeName, StoreLocation location)
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, location);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
    try
    {
        var filteredCerts = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "fiddler", false);
        if (filteredCerts.Count > 0)
            store.RemoveRange(filteredCerts);
    }
    catch { throw; }
    finally { store.Close(); }

}
```

But the problem is, we can do this only for logged-in user, but not for all the users

I also tried entering through registry to get all users from **Computer\HKEY_USERS** and try to loop and get all the system certificates from:
**Computer\HKEY_USERS<user SID>\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates**

```
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.Users, RegistryView.Default))
using (RegistryKey systemCertificates = hklm.OpenSubKey(sid + @"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates", true))
{
    if (systemCertificates != null)
    {
        foreach (var subKeyName in systemCertificates.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not getting all the certificates, is there a way to get all the certificates from all the user while login as Admin?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with Fiddler? I don't see any relation between your question and Fiddler.

Comment: @Robert Actually the certificated which I want to delete is Fiddler certificates (DO_NOT_TRUST), so I thought may be someone from fiddler can also help me

Comment: I would use a login-script. The next time the user log-in the certificates are deleted. BTW: Why do you want t delete them? Usually the do not harm even if the can get quite a lot of them.

Comment: Those are client machines, we don't want to leave any external certificates, that's why. We cannot use login scripts because, some of the users might never login, but still we don't want to leave any certificates.

Comment: Fiddler certificates are not external. They are generated on the PC/user account itself and this includes the Fiddler root CA certificate. Therefore they can't be used by anybody but the user itself.